# How can i get Products by specific category

Tags: react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

i tried all solution available on stackoverflow about filter products bycategory and i'm creating react native app and used node js, none of the are working.

/products?filter[categories]=${item.slug}${Constants.Keys}

/products?category=${item.slug}${Constants.Keys}

can somebody tell me how filter works on woocommerce REST API in node js??

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. A slug is essentially a URL, why would you pass that and expect a category to be returned? You should be doing something like `/products?category=${categoryName}`

Comment: i also tried `/products?category=${categoryName}` but it return all products, not specific category products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if there is a list of all product with something like category_id in there product json 
you should use something like that

this.state.data.filter(category_id==x)

but i guess your doing something wrong which is not typing in strings like :

`http://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?category=${item.id}`

Comment: thanks, link works. as you say we can do it by `this.state.data.filter(category_id==x)` but this is on front end side so it  takes more time than api request